# Getting cannot find HelloWorld.js when running simple nodejs via Docker

Tags: node.js, docker

I was totally following up the tutorial from this chpater: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/docker/docker_setting_nodejs.htm

All plays well but I got error when trying to execute:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --name HellowWorld -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /home/will/Documents/DockerTests/NodeTest node node HelloWorld.js
```

I got my HelloWorld.js under the folder where this command was run.
The exception is:

```
module.js:491
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/will/Documents/DockerTests/NodeTest/HelloWorld.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:598:3
will@will-virtual-machine:~/Documents/DockerTests/NodeTest$
```

Thanks for your reviewing..

Update: I tried running a different command:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --name HellowWorld -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app node node HelloWorld.js
```

The exception shows up:

```
module.js:491
throw err;
^Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/HelloWorld.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:598:3
```

content of HelloWorld.js:
`console.log('Hellow World');`

Command`ls -alh` shows:

`total 12K
drwxrwxr-x 2 will will 4.0K 8月  27 20:38 .
drwxrwxr-x 9 will will 4.0K 8月  27 19:55 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 will will   29 8月  27 19:52 HellowWorld.js`

Comment: whats the content of `/home/will/Documents/DockerTests/NodeTest` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `-w` flag

That flag is used to set the working directory inside the container. So you are setting that to a path that is valid in your host machine and will have nothing inside the container.

Change you docker run statement as below

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --name HellowWorld -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app node node HelloWorld.js
```

Also make sure HelloWorld.js is present in your current directory

Comment: Hi Lalwani..I tried the script, it shows the same excpetion but a bit little different: Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/HelloWorld.js'

Comment: Paste the contents of your `HelloWorld.js` and also output of `ls -alh` in your question

Comment: Post it in question and not comments

Comment: There is a typo in your filename. It is `HellowWorld.js` intead of `HelloWorld.js`. An extra small `w` before `W`